# Scanner cannot read input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
package algo.chapter1.Ex1_1_33;

import java.util.Scanner;
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdOut;


public class MatrixClient
{
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       while(true)
       {
        switch (getInput())
        {
            case 1:
                //Dot Product
                performDotProduct();
                break;

            case 2:
                performMatrixProduct();
                break;

            case 3:
                break;

            case 4:
                break;

            case 5:
                break;

            case 6:
                StdOut.println("Thank You!");
                System.exit(0);
                break;

            default:
                StdOut.println("Invalid Choice!!!");
        }
    }
}

public static int getInput()
{
    StdOut.println("******************************");
    StdOut.println("1.Dot Product");
    StdOut.println("2.Matrix-Matrix product");
    StdOut.println("3.Transpose");
    StdOut.println("4.Matrix-Vector Product");
    StdOut.println("5.Vector-Matrix product");
    StdOut.println("6.Exit");
    StdOut.println("******************************");
    StdOut.print("\nChoose one from the above: ");

    return StdIn.readInt();
}

public static void performDotProduct()
{
    StdOut.print("Enter elements of vector A: ");
    double[] A = readVector();

    StdOut.print("Enter elements of vector B: ");
    double[] B = readVector();

    StdOut.println("The dot product is: " + Matrix.dot(A, B));
}

public static void performMatrixProduct()
{
    StdOut.print("Enter the size of matrix A: ");
    int size = scan.nextInt();

    double[][] A = readMatrix(size);
    for (double[] row : A)
    {
        for (double item : row)
            StdOut.print(item + "\t");
        StdOut.println();
    }
}
public static double[] readVector()
{

    String[] input = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
    double[] x = new double[input.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        x[i] = Double.parseDouble(input[i]);

    return x;
}

public static double[][] readMatrix(int N)
{
    int counter = 0;
    double[][] matrix = new double[N][N];
    while (counter < N)
    {
        StdOut.print("Enter elements of row " + (counter + 1) + ": ");
        matrix[counter] = readVector();
        counter++;
    }

    return matrix;
}
}
```

I'm using readVector() method to read a row of doubles and return a double array. When it is used for dot product, input is being read returned fine, but when I use matrix-matrix multiplication option, readVector() doesn't wait for input. It throws NumberFormatExcpetion: empty string.

I don't understand why readVector() behaves differently.

Comment: have you tried:
String line = sc.nextLine();
String[] input = line.split(" ");

Comment: Long story short, don't mix `nextLine()` with any of the `nextInt/Long/etc.()` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
int size = scan.nextInt();
```

When your code asks to enter the size of the matrix, you enter a number, and then hit enter. The above code, however, only reads the number that you enter. It does not consume the enter (`\n` character).

After your code consume the matrix size, your code does:

```
String[] input = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
```

which consumes the enter (`\n` character), and then split it by space. This (`scan.nextLine()`), of course, returns an empty string.

To fix it, instead of using:

```
int size = scan.nextInt();
```

use:

```
int size = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thank you for deep explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In your code change:

```
 int size = scan.nextInt();
```

To

```
 int size = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```